# mitmproxy with Tor Browser

Tags: selenium, networking, proxy, tor, mitmproxy

I need to use mitmproxy to look at packets sent from my host to the Tor entry node using the Tor Browser. I'm using [tor-browser-selenium](https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium) to automate the Tor Browser, but suggestions need not be specific to this library.  I just need to know how to make my traffic from the Tor Browser first go through this proxy before entering the Tor network.

Is there a way I can do this easily, perhaps using the torrc file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you'd be able to do this would be to change Tor browser's proxy settings to point to the mitmproxy and then configure that to go through Tor's socks proxy.

There's nothing in torrc that would facilitate this otherwise. Tor browser simply proxies through 127.0.0.1:9150 and once there is encrypted and relayed over the Tor network.

If you want to log the traffic, you'll have to get in front of Tor and then send everything through it.

I'm not familiar with mitmproxy receiving traffic and then sending it through another socks proxy to go on to the final destination.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:** It looks like mitmproxy does not support forwarding to an upstream SOCKS proxy. See [here](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/830).

Comment: Thanks!  This is sort of what I suspected.